# MySQL join based on where from 2nd table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables as follows:

**docs**

| id | carid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | doc1 |
| 2 | 1 | doc2 |
| 3 | 2 | doc3 |
| 4 | 1 | doc4 |
| 5 | 5 | doc5 |

**cars**

| carid | parentid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | car1 |
| 2 | 5 | car2 |
| 3 | 4 | car3 |
| 4 | 4 | car4 |
| 5 | 5 | car5 |

**Question:** I want to write a query in mysql where I can pass the carid in where clause and get all the rows from docs table where the parentid is same as that of the passed carid.

**Desired Outcome** If I pass carid=3 then the rows 1,2,4 from docs table should be returned as the parentid is 4 for carids 1,3,4.
Simillarly, If I pass carid=2 then the rows 3,5 from docs table should be returned as the parentid is 5 for carids 2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the `cars`-table twice. First for the condition and second for the parent:

```
select d.*
from cars c
  join cars p on p.parentid=c.parentid
  join docs d on d.carid=p.carid
where c.carid=3
```

Comment: I just totally missed the fact that I can do a self-join. Thanks @slaakso

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this a little wrong in the aspect of a relational database ..  You SHOULD have 4 tables:

**docs**

| doc_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | doc1 |
| 2 | doc2 |
| 3 | doc3 |
| 4 | doc4 |
| 5 | doc5 |

**cars**

| car_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | car1 |
| 2 | car2 |
| 3 | car3 |
| 4 | car4 |
| 5 | car5 |

**cars_to_docs**

| car_id | doc_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 |

**parents_to_car**

| car_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |

Then you could simply use a basic JOIN

```
SELECT b.doc_id FROM test.docs a

LEFT JOIN test.cars_to_docs b
ON a.doc_id = b.car_id

LEFT JOIN test.parents_to_car c
ON c.car_id = b.car_id

LEFT JOIN test.cars d
ON c.car_id = d.car_id

WHERE c.parent_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM test.parents_to_car WHERE car_id = 3)
```

This will give you your output of 1,2,4

Comment: I see no benefit of junction tables here; a docs row has a carid, not multiple ones, and a car has a parent car, not multiple ones